# Command to display whole row based on searching column in linux?

Tags: linux, shell, redhat

I have  rows like this

```
A006            Anand          E1       01       12450.00
A005            John           E2       01       14500.00
```

I have been trying:

```
cut -f3 emp | grep 'E2'
```

Output:

```
E2
```

I want to extract the whole row. I dont want to use awk command.

Comment: Unless you must not use awk, overcome your petty desires and do so!  It is the right tool.

Comment: Why don't you want to use awk? The awk solution is almost trivial: `awk '$3=="E2"' emp`

Comment: Actually i dont know much about awk command...thats y i dont prefer to use it at this time. :)...Thanx for your help sir.

Answer (score 0):

That is how `cut` works. You can use only `grep`, but the regualr expression is going to be complicated:

```
grep $'^[^\t]\+\t[^\t]\+\tE2\t'
```

It uses the bash's `$''` expansion to introduce `\t` for a tab. It says: search for a line that starts with some non-tab characters followed by a tab followed by several non-tab characters followed by a tab followed by E2 and a tab.

Comment: Thanx for your help...This is a bit complicated.